# Hide entire Pivot Table in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Is there a way to hide an entire pivot table if there is no data to display?  The screenshot of a pivot table get its data from "Sheet2".  If there is no data in "Sheet2" selection then I Want to hide entire pivot table.  Is this possible?

[image]

Here's how the pivot table looks when there is no data in "Sheet2":

[image]

Let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Just hide those rows?

Comment: Unfortunately, the spreadsheet gets populated automatically via our ERP system using markup language (string &=S1.SNAME2  lets excel know what to populate there).  This spreadsheet is a template to populate rent for thousands of tenants.  We want to avoid manual steps as much as possible.  That is why I am looking for a solution to hide entire pivot if blank.

Comment: Just programmatically hide those rows?